# Does android support the Device Profile for Web Services (dpws)?

Tags: android, web-services

I want use webservices (using Soap and not rest) on android and I want use dpws (not ksoap2).
Is there any dpws library available for android?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support DPWS. but u can use JMEDs(DPWS stack implemented in java) in the andorid. I have created DPWS server and client using this JMEDs stack in android device.

http://ws4d.e-technik.uni-rostock.de/jmeds/version_2/

Hope this will help. :-)

Comment: Naveen, does this mean , that I can't use JMED client for android for existing SOAP service( without the DPWS ) ?